# pgfplot: centering the axis above the caption without trimming axes

Tags: pgfplots

is there a stable way to center the axis (without the axis label) above a figure caption without trimming the axis with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
```

? Trimming the axis works fine until I don't have more than one tikzpicture per row.

The left axis is centered like I want it (by trimming); the right is not centered.

[image]

When I trim also the right one, I get this result

[image]

This would be the (faked) way I want it

[image]

SORRY, here is an MWE:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\pgfplot}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=.48\textwidth,
        %height=\figureheight,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$]
        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (2,3)
            (3,1)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]%
\begin{center}
\subfigure[Caption 1]{
    \pgfplot
}
\subfigure[Caption 2]{
    \pgfplot
}\\
\caption{Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption.}%
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: The easiest way would be to create your own caption using a tikz node.  It's not like \subfigure writes to the LOF file.

Answer (score 1):

First you have some spurious end of line spaces. Second, you can use `\hfil` or `\hfill` along with `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]`. Third `subfigure` is deprecated, use `subfig` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}   %% better use 1.11 instead of newest

\newcommand{\pgfplot}{%      %%<----- put % here
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=.48\textwidth,
        %height=\figureheight,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$]
        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (2,3)
            (3,1)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%   %%<----- put % here
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]%
%\begin{center}
\centering    %% use this instead of \begin{center}
\subfloat[Caption 1]{\pgfplot}
\hfil    %% or \hfill
\subfloat[Caption 2]{\pgfplot}%\\
\caption{Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption Overall caption.}%
%\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]